# Best design pattern for Android UI visibility control?

Tags: android, design-patterns

It is very common for Android app to display and hide UI elements. For example, when you signup an account, there may be 3 pages,

> Enter phone number page-> Receive msg verification page -> Enter
>   username and password page

I wonder what is the best design pattern for this? My first thought is using mvc and state machine. View layer is only responsible for UI elements' visibility. Every page will be a state, when entering to a different state, I will enable some elements and disable some elements. But in this way, I have to implement many states if there are many different pages. Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually i work a bit like you said. I have a state function to show different kind of views, which have their different behaviors. You can do this with Views included on a activity, or with different fragments for "heavier content" with transitions to each other. Then I manage and save them state on onSaveInstanceState on main activity. Hope it helps

Comment: But it is very common that there will be 20+ pages in the app, does that mean i have to have 20+ states?

Comment: Well, a viewpager can do that for you easily.